# Mapping through an array of objects error - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to map through an array of objects returned from a third party api to return certain object values, but there's a bug with my map function and I can't work out why. I've tested to ensure the rest of my code is behaving as it should, it's just this one map function I can't seem to get working.

This is my current code:

```
async function displayRecipeCard(inputString) {
 
 const recipes = await getRecipeInfo(inputString); //fetches data from api and returns an object
 const recipeResults = recipes.results; // returns an array of objects

 const recipeCard = recipeResults.map(recipe => {
   return recipe.title; 
 });
};
```

Returning:

```
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined
```

Now if I write:

```
async function displayRecipeCard(inputString) {
  const recipes = await getRecipeInfo(inputString);
  const recipeResults = await recipes.results;
  
  return recipeResults[0].title;
};
```

It returns the title of the first array object element, as expected:

```
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined
```

Can anybody notice any mistakes in my code or have any idea what the issue could be?

Thank you!

Comment: are you saying the values of `recipeCard` is a promise which resolves to undefined? Or are you saying that the call to `displayRecipeCard()` is giving a promise which resolves to undefined? If it's `displayRecipeCard()` that's because you're not returning anything from the `displayRecipeCard` function

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're saying, it would seem that `results` is a promise. So you need to await that promise, then `map` the array it fulfills with:

```
async function displayRecipeCard(inputString) {
    const recipes = await getRecipeInfo(inputString);
    //              ^^^^^−−−−− you'll want to double-check that this is necessary
    const recipeResults = await recipes.results;
    //                    ^^^^^−−−−− looks like you need this one though
   
    const recipeCard = recipeResults.map(({title}) => title); // Your original was fine, but this shows using destructuring if you like
} // Note: No `;` on function declarations
```

Fundamentally, you need to check the documentation (or implementation) of `getReceiptInfo` to be sure what it returns, and then `await` any promises before doing the `map`.

Comment: *(Gah! Editing error. If you see "you'll want to double-check that this is necessary" twice above, hit refresh.)*